# In beamer, why do images seem to be distorted when using 16:9 ratio?

Tags: beamer

I am having a slight issue. My images in `beamer` seem to be distorted when using a 16:9 aspect ratio, but fine if I do standard 4:3.

Can anyone provide any assistance or help with this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

To include images, I use the following code

```
\includegraphics[scale=x.xx]{NAME.png}
```

where x.xx is changed to have the image fit on the slide properly. Usually it is set to betwee 0.60 and 0.80.

Comment: Please show is how you include your images. The most likely explanation would be that you specify both the with and the height of your images.

Comment: Added to original post. I don't specify widths/heights, only a scaling parameter.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do your mean "smaller compared to the paper width" if you say distorted?

Answer (score 3):

The scale option scales the image relative to the original size of the image. If you change the `aspectratio` of the beamer slide, the paper width changes and the image will look smaller compared to the width of the frame. If this is not the behaviour you want, you can specify the with of the image relative to the width of the frame:

```
\documentclass[
aspectratio=169
]{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: would `keepaspectratio` option, not work here?

Comment: @Raaja I don't think the images are actually distorted, so I don't think `keepaspectratio` would help -- but I hope the OP will further clarify the question

Comment: Ahhh, like that, clear!